# Optimizing large list View in Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I Am trying to fetch data from `http, json array` and display in `list view` and there is over 1000 items and loading all of them at once makes scrolling so laggy and am trying to load 20 items first and when scrolled down i want to load more 20 items but my code is not working. Can anyone help me out.

HTML

```
 <ion-content ng-controller="ListController" on-infinite-scroll="addMoreItem"     class="has-subheader" scroll-watch >
      <ion-list >
        <ion-item href="{{ item.url }}.jpg" ng-repeat="item in id | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" >
          <img src="{{ item.thumbnailUrl }}.jpg" alt="Photo">
          <h2>
            {{item.id}}
          </h2>
          <p>{{item.title}}</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

AngularJS

```
 .controller('ListController',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
     $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').success(function(data){     
    $scope.id = data;
   })
     $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 20; // number of item to load each time 
     $scope.addMoreItem = function(done) {
     if ($scope.item.length >= $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay)
     $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 20; // load 20 more items
      done(); // need to call this when finish loading more data
   }
   }])
```

Comment: you should go for `<ion-item collection-repeat="item in items">` which is by far more performant for huge lists,

Comment: I need 15 Reputation to vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with huge lists, ionic suggest that you should use the `collection-repeat` directive instead of `ng-repeat` cause it gives a far more better performance. `collection-repeat` renders into the DOM only as many items as are currently visible and thats how it keeps the performance up. Please read more on the official doc here: [collection-repeat](https://ionicframework.com/blog/collection-repeat-iteration-two/)

Comment: link not found!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solving it through [infinite-scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll).. :)